# Django collectstatic command for specific file or folder

Tags: django, static, root, collectstatic

when I run this code

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
```

it remove all static files and folders in staticroot and colletc all files and folders again. But I want to collect just a specific file or a specific folder. How can i do that?

Comment: Why do you need to use `--clear`?

Answer (score 8):

`collectstatic` doesn't support whitelists, all it supports is blacklists (ignoring file patterns), so you will have to list everything you don't want to be synced:

```
python manage.py collectstatic -i folder1 -i *.jpeg
```

Comment: @GuilhermeIA the `-i` flag means 'ignore' so it will ignore things in `folder1/` and files ending in `.jpeg`